# MySQL Phantom tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I did a drop query on a MySQL table... my GUI interface crashed right in the middle of the process.  The table does not exist in the listing; however, when I go to make a new one it says that there is already a table with that name.  I tried doing a DROP TABLE and a RENAME on this phantom table but both queries run endlessly.

FYI I am unable to restart MySQL because shit might break on our live sites.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried both navicat and mysql workbench... I don't think the gui is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the command line client?

Comment: Yes I'm actually getting a file not found on the .frm file when executing queries on this phantom table.  This takes about 10 minutes to pop up as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up restoring from a backup... editing files in the file system is scary and may have required a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the table : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: Repairing table does not work it returns two result sets:
'Table does not exist' AND 'Corrupt'

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Then, you have to directly manipulate the table's files. See the other answers for details.

Answer (score 0):

The tablename matches three files in the filesystem with a `.frm`, `.myd` and `.myi` extension *(for the table definition, data and index files respectively)*  One of these files is corrupted, which prevents MySQL from carrying out your order.

**Option 1 delete files from the filesystem**
Have a look at the filesystem to see which file still exists.
If the .frm file is missing, you should be able to delete the other two files.
If the .frm file is still there **do not delete**, MySQL still has a lock on that file.

**Option 2 repair the database**
Use the `myisamchk` to diagnose and repair your database.

See: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_File_Formats
And: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-repair.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory where mysql stores the databases. On Ubuntu it's in /var/lib/mysql, but it may be different depending on your OS and configuration. Inside that directory there is a directory for every database, go into the directory for the problematic database, and delete any file that are the table name with extensions .frm, .myd, and .myi.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a disconnect between what you have and what your server *thinks* you have.

You'll need SSH access and have to repair the table manually.

Log in to SSH and type:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And enter your root mysql password.

Then

```
show databases
```

And it will list all the databases on your server.

Select the database you want with

```
use databasename;
```

Then

```
show tables;
```

This should list every table in your database.  It's likely that it's still shows up there, so do a

```
drop tablename;
```

Hopefully that will correct your issue.